# Issue with import Parse - No such module Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform, cocoapods

I installed the Parse iOS SDK with Cocoapod and wanted to import it in my `appDelegate`.

But I have the error `No such module Parse` even if I try to clean the build. Also I have a lot of warning coming from Parse AND Bolt (a dependency).

I downgrade the package from the current 1.15.3 (at the time of this writing) to 1.14.4 but have the same trouble.

here my Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'BookBank' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for BookBank
  pod 'Parse'

end
```

Any idea ?

## Edit

I think I found out why. Even opening the `*.xcworkspace` file XCode didn't seem to link with the Cocoapod libraries. I try with Alamofire or other well known package and I had the same issue. So it was pointing out it wasn't a library problem.

I google for a day (and lost a day of working) and I solve my issue.
I had to change the scheme of the app like so

Click on the upper-left of XCode on your app's name

[image: xcode]

Then `Manage Schemes`

[image]

And finally change your app container to the one with the workplace.

[image]

Clean the build et voilà !